# Spring Boot - Authentication null

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a link on my home page that leads to users posts page. It is visible only if user is logged in. Currently I'm getting

```
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getPrincipal()" because "auth" is null
```

when I try to get on homepage as a guest. I understand that Authentication requires a logged in user, but how exactly can I handle that exception or is there a better way to do it?

My controller

```
...
@GetMapping("/home")
public String home (Model model, Authentication auth) {

    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) auth.getPrincipal();
    User user = userPrincipal.getUser();

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("listPosts", postService.getAllPosts());

    return "home";
}
...
```

Link in my thymeleaf view

```
<li><a th:href="@{/{username}/posts (username = ${user.username})}" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">My posts</a></li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine if the `Authentication` is present first:

```
public String home (Model model, Authentication auth) {
    if (auth != null && auth instanceof UserPrincipal) {
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) auth.getPrincipal();
        model.addAttribute("user", userPrincipal.getUser());
    }

    model.addAttribute("listPosts", postService.getAllPosts());

    return "home";
}
```

But then you would need to also handle the user coming through as null in the thymeleaf template.

You could leave it as null or inject a 'Guest' `User` object if not present to handle it that way.

Comment: I've passed a null User object in my "else" block, but I removed "auth instanceof UserPrincipal" in my if statement. If I leave that second condition, the auth!=null check gets covered by it and it always ends up executing the else block which contains null User. Thank you for your help!